# Exemplify when an augmented matrix with pivot every row can still be consistent.

Tags: matrices

While I read I come across:
[image]

In the 'warning' section, it claims an augmented matrix with pivot every row 'may be consistent'. However, I cannot think of any example or cases when this stands, given we don't consider 0 rows having any pivot.

Can anyone give me an example supporting this claim? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of an augmented matrix with pivots in each row with no solution:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & | & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

An example of an augmented matrix with pivots in each row with a solution:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & | & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$